# How to get the location geotag from an Instagram post using the API

Tags: python, instagram-api

I'm trying to get the location geotag from an already posted Instagram post using the Basic Display Instagram API?

I can't find any endpoints that let me get the location. Am I missing something or is that something we just cannot do?

Comment: I just find it so odd given how it's such a commonly used attribute when posting.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It appears at this time you can only set the `location-id` when creating a piece of media via the API but it is not available when retrieving a piece of media.

POST call to API
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media#create-photo-container

Fields available when making a GET call
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media#fields

Comment: Ok, that is the same conclusion I got to as well. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: Is there a workaround for this or no?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using the data365.co Instagram API with which I work.

If you have a post ID or shortcode, you can build a task to download it via a POST request:
https://api.data365.co/v1.1/instagram/post/CYjV-nusXA8/update?access_token=TOKEN

This GET request returns you the information about the publication:
https://api.data365.co/v1.1/instagram/post/CYjV-nusXA8?access_token=TOKEN

You receive such a list of fields, including the location_id:

```
{
    "data": {
    

"attached_media_content": null,
    "attached_media_display_url": "https://instagram.fclj4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/271671353_2486006594877541_7824177366520402526_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fclj4-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=101&_nc_ohc=6N-Dwpx8IvEAX9Zjcvp&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT88wqJiMtaSe4Ma8xtcixRCdaIozxnXKK_6k1W-84k3ZQ&oe=61E6FF84&_nc_sid=83d603",
    "attached_media_tagged_users": [
        "dilettazamba.iti",
        "laura_medeghini"
    ],
    "attached_video_url": null,
    "comments_count": 8,
    "created_time": "2022-01-10T14:04:24",
    "id": "2748136859869737020",
    "is_comments_disabled": false,
    "is_video": false,
    "likes_count": 257,
    "location_id": "447269731",
    "owner_id": "182171607",
    "related_posts": null,
    "shortcode": "CYjV-nusXA8",
    "sponsors": [
        "dilettazamba.iti",
        "laura_medeghini"
    ],
    "text": "Pretending it was not all about grappa #italiansdoitbetter",
    "text_lang": "en",
    "text_tagged_users": null,
    "text_tags": [
        "italiansdoitbetter"
    ],
    "timestamp": 1641823464,
    "video_plays_count": null,
    "video_views_count": null
    },
    "error": null,
    "status": "ok"
}
```

If you need to get more location data, you can create a task to download location information.

An creating a task example, POST request:

https://api.data365.co/v1.1/instagram/location/447269731/update?access_token=TOKEN

Example of getting data, GET request:

https://api.data365.co/v1.1/instagram/location/447269731?access_token=TOKEN

An example of location data from a GET request:

```
{
    "data": {
        "address": null,
        "city": null,
        "country_code": "IT",
        "description": null,
        "external_url": "http://www.regione.lombardia.it/",
        "has_public_page": false,
        "id": "447269731",
        "is_exact_city_match": null,
        "is_exact_country_match": null,
        "is_exact_region_match": true,
        "latitude": 45.65,
        "longitude": 9.95,
        "name": "Lombardy",
        "phone": null,
        "posts_count": 752322,
        "primary_alias_on_fb": "234765516537015",
        "region": "Lombardia",
        "slug": "lombardy",
        "thumb_url": "https://instagram.fhel6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s150x150/133538449_422161569029342_6176236793032572073_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=TKr1bwmeTxsAX8c_2AW&tp=1&oh=6d7d9df9654741083884c5880496fc5a&oe=60269982",
        "zip_code": null
    },
    "error": null,
    "status": "ok"
}
```

You can see more information about our API capability and the data it provides at https://data365.co/instagram.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by opening the post, right-clicking on top of the post, tick mark Properties, and then Location. You will get a map with location coordinates in decimal degrees which you can use to pinpoint that spot on Google Maps or another mapping service. APIs calculate this too but APIs are for developers only so it is not accessible to an average Instagram user unless you're building an app related to it.

Comment: The OP is asking how to do this via API, not through the UI.